# Find the first file that matches a pattern using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to select any one ".xls" file in a directory. The problem is the [dir](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) command can return different types.

```
gci *.xls
```

will return

- object[] if there is more than one file
- FileInfo if there is exactly one file
- null if there are no files

I can deal with null, but how do I just select the "first" file?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can force PowerShell into returning an array, even when only one item is present by wrapping a statement into `@(...)`:

```
@(gci *.xls)[0]
```

will work for each of your three cases:

- it returns the first object of a collection of files
- it returns the only object if there is only one
- it returns `$null` of there wasn't any object to begin with

---

There is also the `-First` parameter to `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xls | Select-Object -First 1
gci -fi *.xls | select -f 1
```

which works pretty much identical to the above, except that the list of files doesn't need to be enumerated completely by `Get-ChildItem`, as the pipeline is aborted after the first item. This can make a difference when there are many files matching the filter.